# YAML based azure build pipeline to run particular tasks based on condition?

Tags: azure-devops, azure, azure-pipelines, build-pipeline, yaml

Need to create a YAML based azure build pipeline i.e, need to run particular tasks like only build step when it is PR automated and when the same pipeline  manually run it should run build task along with archive and publish artifact tasks

Answer (score 1):

Yes; you can use the [Build.Reason pre-defined variable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in a task [condition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), like this for example:

```
condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
```